# Правописание: "не нужных" или "ненужных"

Tags: орфография

Как пишется слово "ненужных" в данном контексте? *"Не существует не нужных. Есть брошенные".* Желательно с объяснением. Пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не существует **ненужных**. Есть брошенные.

Ненужные — субстантивированное прилагательное (переход прилагательного в существительное), поэтому написание слитное.

Само прилагательное "ненужный" обычно пишется раздельно при усилении отрицания: никому не нужный.

Answer (score 1):

Не только ненужный, но и все остальные прилагательные пишутся с НЕ слитно, если нет противопоставления с союзом а, слов ВОВСЕ, ДАЛЕКО, ОТНЮДЬ и слов с приставкой НИ. А здесь следует рассмотреть, как вы правильно, Sibylla, сказали не прилагательное, а существительное с приставкой НЕ. Правило то же самое. Нет союза а, слов ВОВСЕ, ДАЛЕКО, ОТНЮДЬ и слов с приставкой НИ. Поэтому "ненужных" пишем слитно ("не существует  ненужных").